# google maps api: display an arrow to indicate that there is a marker not visible on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've an html application that uses javascript Google Maps API to display some points (markers). Some of the points may not be visible in the current user map (due to zoom, position, etc.). I was looking for somehow to represent this points, for example, an arrow on near the border of the map indicating the direction.

Is there any function / library that may help?

In case there isn't.
I've analyzes how to implement this by myself. The direction of the arrow can be achieved by (MarkerPosition - CenterPosition).normalize(). However, how can I draw that arrow in the correct position on the border of the map?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it would be doable.  Do you have a data set where it makes sense to do this?  If there are _lots_ of markers all around, how do you want it to behave?

Comment: As no solution found. I'm developing it. I'll publish it when finished.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes I have a set of data. The markers are obtained from a service where the ammount is controlled, so there isn't any problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed a solution to the problem.
Source code can be found at github.com

https://github.com/mateuyabar/GmapsHiddenMarkers

And a [sample map](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://raw.github.com/mateuyabar/GmapsHiddenMarkers/master/sample.html)